# All value in a SQL syntax with precompiled query

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have this SQL query:

`SELECT *

FROM MyTable t

WHERE [any condition] AND t.range = x`

The attribute `t.range` value is included in [0, 90].
So, the user have two possibility:

1. insert a value
2. view all value

Now, it's can do the point 2 *without delete* the part `AND t.range =` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE [any condition] 
AND (t.range = x or x is null)
```